# Clone failing against my new Windows 7 Git server using copssh, msysgit

Tags: windows, git, clone, head

I have created a git server on my Windows 7 box following [Tim Davis' tutorial](http://www.timdavis.com.au/git/setting-up-a-msysgit-server-with-copssh-on-windows/)
Got everything working up to the part of actually trying to clone the repository.
I have a repo located on my server at:
C:\SSH\home\repos\testapp.git that I have initialized using git --bare init as per the tutorial, and try to clone it using GiT GUI via:
ssh://repos@myurl/SSH/home/repos/testapp.git

but get an error dialog popping up describing "Clone failed.  Cannot determine HEAD.  See console output for details." and "Couldn't find remote ref HEAD".

I tried making a new repo out of an existing project folder (hoping that this 'ref' would magically correct itself) but the same thing message occurs.

Is there something more after a '--bare' or an 'init' that needs to be done to set the head reference?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably it's failing because it is an empty repository. You can try to add an initial ( dummy commit if needed ) to the repository and try the cloning again. Steps below if you don't know to do this.

Can you do this:

```
cd /home/repos
mkdir testapp.wd
cd testapp.wd
git clone ../testapp.git .
<now add some file>
touch README
git add README
git commit -m "Adding a initial commit"
git push origin master
cd ..
rm -rf testapp.wd
```

Now see if you can do the clone that you were trying.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the reply mate! I followed your suggestion but at the "git add README" I get the following error:$ git add README
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git.  I had created a file in explorer called README in the testapp.wd folder and the touch README succeeded.  Seems like you got me closer. :).  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, I missed a  ending . in `git clone ../testapp.git .` Either do that, or after the `git clone ../testapp.git` do a `cd testapp.git` and then continue with the `touch README` Updated instructions

Comment: Wow...thanks a bunch man...I really appreciate the help and your patience with a git noob. The '.' was all that was needed and my lack of experience with the git commands didn't help. Finally got git running on my Win 7 box and thanks for taking me to the finish line...now it's on to learning the git commands. Best Regards mate.

Answer (score 2):

If remote repository is empty, it will happen. Try to commit something.